# How to convert files in Unix using iconv?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, iconv

I'm new to Bash scripting. I have a requirement to convert multiple input files in UTF-8 encoding to ISO 8859-1.

I am using the below command, which is working fine for the conversion part:

```
cd ${DIR_INPUT}/
for f in *.txt; do iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 $f > ${DIR_LIST}/$f; done
```

However, when I *don't* have any text files in my input directory (`$DIR_INPUT`), it still creates an empty `.txt` file in my output directory (`$DIR_LIST`).

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: `… do iconv …` → `… do [ -e "$f" ] && iconv …`

Comment: (OT: Quote your variables! [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend. And there’s probably no need to `cd`.)

Answer (score 1):

The empty file `*.txt` is being created in your output directory because by default, bash expands an unmatched expansions to the literal string that you supplied. You can change this behaviour in a number of ways, but what you're probably looking for is `shopt -s nullglob`. Observe:

```
$ for i in a*; do echo "$i"; done
a*
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for i in a*; do echo "$i"; done
$
```

You can find documentation about this in the bash man page under *Pathname Expansion*. Or [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) or [here](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs).

In your case, I'd probably rewrite this in this way:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in "$DIR_INPUT"/*.txt; do
  iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 "$f" > "${DIR_LIST}/${f##*/}"
done
```

This avoids the need for the initial `cd`, and uses parameter expansion to strip off the path portion of `$f` for the output redirection. The `nullglob` will obviously eliminate the work being done on a nonexistent file.

Answer (score 1):

As @ghoti pointed out, in the absence of files matching the [wildcard](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html#AEN17581) expression `a*` the expression itself becomes the result of pathname expansion. By default (when `nullglob` option is unset), `a*` is expanded to, literally, `a*`.

You can set `nullglob` option, of course. But then you should be aware of the fact that all subsequent pathname expansions will be affected, unless you unset the option after the loop.

I would rather use `find` command which has a clear interface (and, in my opinion, is less likely to perform implicit conversions as opposed to the Bash [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)). E.g.:

```
cmd='iconv --verbose -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 "$0" > "$1"/$(basename "$0")'

find "${DIR_INPUT}/" \
    -mindepth 1 \
    -maxdepth 1 \
    -type f \
    -name '*.txt' \
    -exec sh -c "$cmd" {} "${DIR_LIST}" \;
```

In the example above, `$0` and `$1` are positional arguments for the file path and `${DIR_LIST}` respectively. The command is invoked via standard shell (`sh`) because of the need to refer to the file path `{}` twice. Although most modern implementations of `find` may handle multiple occurrences of `{}` correctly, the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) states:

> If more than one argument containing the two characters "{}" is present, the behavior is unspecified.

As in the `for` loop, the `-name` pattern `*.txt` is evaluated as true if the basename of the current pathname matches the operand (`*.txt`) using the [pattern matching notation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13). But, unlike the `for` loop, **filename expansion** do not apply as this is a matching operation, not an expansion.